# Sql database design for null column on first insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-normalization

We have a table in an sql database with three columns: `t1c1`, `t1c2`, and `t1c3`.

When I insert new rows in the table I will fill the values for first two columns (`t1c1` and `t1c2`), but the third column (`t1c3`) will always be null upon first insertion. After that something happens inside the system and it will fill the value for `t1c3`.

My question is about normalization. Should the `t1c3` column really be part of `table1` or should it be part of another table (`table2`) with just one column (`t2c1`) which is equal to (`t1c3`).

Comment: This could only happen consistently if you had a trigger on the table.  Otherwise, it is an error in your insert code.

Comment: I would disagree. There may be cases where this can happen. Example: we have a user tabl with id, name and address. initially we may not have address upon user authentication but in later point time after email authentication the user may want to provide his address which will fill the third column.

Comment: @niteshmalav . . . I interpret your question as saying that the DATABASE makes the third column `NULL` on the first insertion.  For that you need a trigger.  As usual, sample data and desired results would probably clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Understood. I wanted to give one sample like above but it would again focus on only one aspect of the use-case which may interpret problem differently whereas some other use case may infer differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need two columns: one with the key from `table1`, and one with the `tcl3` value, so you could relate the values in `table2` back to the correct rows in `table1`. However, it doesn't seem necessary to do that in this case.

Comment: My understanding is simple here. If i am inserting something in a table and one of the column is NULL then i would rather keep that field in another table as that value will be filled later then it is representing another entity for me.

Comment: Then it should apply in this case as well.

Comment: If it really represents another entity, then it should be in another table. But it's not automatically correct to infer a column represents another entity just because it starts out with a NULL value.

Comment: Yes, I see. I guess it is again use case specific.